# Reopen 'Origin of the phrase "Looks like Tarzan, plays like Jane"?'

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

This is a request to reopen the question '[Origin of the phrase "Looks like Tarzan, plays like Jane"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85659/origin-of-the-phrase-looks-like-tarzan-plays-like-jane)'. There were at least 4 reopen votes previously which appear to have expired (?). This appears to have now dwindled to 1.

I consider the question on-topic and useful and the arguments against its validity to be specious.

Comment: Origin pf phrases/quotes are sometimes considered off-topic. Also, the question was closed as 'not constructive' not 'off-topic'.

Comment: I think my question was poorly phrased to start out.  My addition that "Looks like Tarzan, plays like Jane" is part of a standard lingo for NFL scouts helped to make the question more specific and constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I concur. The stated reason for closing the question was that "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

In fact, coleopterist provided an answer which **was** supported by facts and references; and I was (to my surprise) able to support this with further facts and references, which showed his answer was about as close to a certainty as can reasonably be expected.

Comment: I must be missing something. It already has a fine answer. Is the purpose of re-opening solely to prevent its deletion, or is there some other reason?

Comment: @AndrewLeach  To prevent deletion, but more importantly to remove an undeserved stigma which tells future posters that this sort of question should be avoided.

Comment: I think that that this phrase could potentially be cited to a particular individual other than Reagan, even though the answer is a really good one.  I think the question should stay open in case we do get such a canonical answer.  If that answer doesn't come, I'll accept coleopterist's answer.

Comment: @coleopterist  Would you care to edit your answer to incorporate the corroboration I turned up? Or, failing that, would you mind if I did so?

Answer (score 1):

> There were at least 4 reopen votes previously which appear to have expired.

Votes to close/re-open a question expire; how quickly they expire depends on many factors, including the number of views the question has. If the number of views is lower than X, then the votes expire slower.

An expiration policy avoids that, for example, and old question that over time collected random votes to close (made by users who didn't read it carefully, or who misunderstood it) is closed. The idea is that if a question needs to be closed, a consensus is reached quickly.